# ¿Cómo hacer una función que busque y borre de un array numérico el número recibido por parámetro?

Tags: javascript, array, function

La funcion `buscaDestruye` recibe como argumento un array de enteros `arreglo` y un entero `num`. Esta función tiene que eliminar los números del array que coincidan con el número recibido como argumento (`num`). La función debe retornar el `array` sin los números sacados.

```
Ej: buscaDestruye([1, 2, 3, 4], 2) devuelve => [1, 3, 4]
```

Si el numero se repite mas de una vez, también hay que eliminarlo.

```
Ej: buscaDestruye([1, 2, 3, 4, 1], 1) devuelve => [2, 3, 4]
```

---

```
function buscaDestruye(arreglo, num) {


}
```

Comment: Ya hay una funcion nativa que hace eso, pero me imagino que requieres crear una propia.

Comment: ¿@Riven que función nativa en JavaScript hace eso? Está claro que con un ‘filter’ se hace en una línea pero no conozco ninguna función nativa con esa firma.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una forma de resolverlo:

```
function buscaDestruye(arreglo, num) {
let newArray = [];
  for(let unElemento of arreglo){
    if(!(unElemento == num)){
      newArray.push(unElemento);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

Creamos un array de retorno, si el elemento del array no coincide con el pasado por el parámetro, lo añadimos al nuevo array. Es una solución básica pero podría ser muy poco eficiente analizado el caso, es por eso qué deberías ver la eficacia del algoritmo en el tamaño del array y el tiempo de respuesta.